# General update pattern not working as expected with d3.selection

Tags: d3.js

I am puzzling over why the following simple update pattern doesn't work. This follows the recommended [General Update Pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) , as far as I can see.

```
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>
...
    var dat = ["One","Two","Buckle my shoe"];
    var sel = d3.selectAll("p.test").data(dat);
    sel.enter().append("p").classed("test", true);
    sel.exit().remove();

    //update 1 ... doesn't work
    sel.text(function(d) { return d;})
```

The paragraphs get created fine, but the text isn't set. However, if I do this:

```
     //update 2 ... this works as expected
     d3.selectAll("p.test").text(function(d) { return d;});
```

...everything works fine. The first version has always worked in the past.

**Update**: I tried using the full d3 library ...

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

... and the first version works again. Do I need more than d3.selection?

To clarify, my past practice has been to define a separate update function that takes the selection as a parameter. Eg, `function doUpdate(sel) { sel.text(...);}`This is for cases where I expect the data elements to have few changes in *size*, but many changes in *content*. Storing the selection as a variable and repeatedly running updates on it has worked well before.

Comment: In d3.js version 4 .enter() and .remove() is not sufficient you have to use .merge() https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_merge That may have something to do with the fact that your update1 does not work... If you look at the example you provided it makes use of merge(). Try sticking `.merge(text)
      .text(function(d) { return d; });`  after your `.classed("test", true)`

Comment: Although this may require the use of d3-transition since you are use .enter(), .exit(), .remove() and .merge()... So you may want to try including that.

Comment: @Yourinium thanks for your comments. I am not using transitions though, and I already have a work-around that doesn't require adding extra scripts. I reviewed the link you posted however, and can confirm that adding the transition, color, dispatch, ease, interpolate and timer scripts made no difference to the problem - for what that's worth.

Comment: I did try replacing the faulty update section with this: `sel.merge(sel).text(function(d) { return d;});` which is what I think @Yourinium had in mind. This didn't work either.

Comment: Got it! Thanks @Yourinium, have posted my own answer.

Comment: Glag you figured it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after studying the release notes, it seems this is not going to be backwardly compatible, for some good reasons. First, the short answer:

Replace this:

```
sel.enter().append("p").classed("test", true);
...
sel.text(function(d) { return d;})     //update block
```

with this:

```
var update = sel.enter().append("p").classed("test", true).merge(sel);
...
update.text(function(d) { return d;})    //update block
```

The reason for this is described  [in this article](https://medium.com/@mbostock/what-makes-software-good-943557f8a488#.cwn2o4ohw) (thanks @mbostock) and is a fix for empty selector problems with v3. The point I missed at first was that the enter() block *needs to run first* so that the merge() block has a populated selection to work on. Which means that the merge() call must come off the end of the enter() block chain.

The format of the change documents sort of hid that, because many examples use chains of function calls. I'm used to splitting the enter/update blocks into separate variables. This aids readability (usually) and means I can farm out the enter/update actions to separate functions - more reusable code that way.

So with that in mind, this **doesn't** work:

```
var enter = sel.enter();
var update = enter.merge(sel); //Nope! Not populated at this point.
enter.append(...);             //too late! Update block uses an empty selection.
```

But this works okay

```
var enter = sel.enter();
enter.append(...);
var update = enter.merge(sel);  //defined after block is populated
```

Comment: Thank you for this explainer. I wasted a lot of time searching for "Cannot read property 'setProperty' of undefined" and "Cannot read property 'getPropertyValue' of undefined".